# worksheet.calculate method looping

Tags: excel, vba

My project is kind of a simulation. It computes the formulas in a set of worksheets repeatedly with differing input data. These worksheets are created for each run from scratch by the VBA macro based on templates, assembling blocs of cells with formulas like LEGO bricks. The workhorse of the simulation is the “worksheet.calculate” method. It does not work anymore since a while, and I could not find the reason. The code lines below are those, where execution of the macro gets caught in an “eternal” loop. Execution of the code line “ws_C_S.Calculate” takes forever.  The task manager shows Excel using 50% to 90% of CPU in this phase and the computer starts to make remarkable noise after a few minutes (may be due to heavy disk operations). I am running Office 365 under Windows 10 64-bit and set the Option explicit option in every module. The saved workbook appears to be fine. It behaves okay when opened stand-alone by hand.
Suggestions how to fix this would be highly appreaciated.

Here are the code lines, where execution gets caught:

```
    ' create a fresh CalculBook with 1 worksheet and save it as xlsb file
    Set wb_C = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Set ws_C_S = wb_C.Worksheets(1)
    ws_C_S.Name = ws_S_Name
    wb_C.SaveAs Filename:=CalculBookFullName, FileFormat:=xlExcel12
    MsgBox "going to calculate the SystemSheet in the CalculBook"
'    Here I had originally a number of Copy > PasteFormulas operations
'    I removed them piece by piece because the final calculation failed
‘    I hoped to identify some faulty formulas this way
'    But the error continues to happen even without any formulas in the worksheet!
    ws_C_S.Activate ‘ it tried it with and without activating the worksheet, leading to the same result
    ws_C_S.Calculate
    MsgBox "SystemSheet calculated"
```

Comment: And what kind of formulas are we talking about? And how many?

Comment: The SystemSheet of a realistic application is typically 400 rows by 100 cols, with about half the cells occupied. The most time consuming functions call an Add-In calculating material properties.There are some VBA functions belonging to my VBA project, e.g. a Riemann Solver, which has as input two 3x6 matrices. There are excel CSE functions like MINVERSE on 3x3 matrices .Most cells contain simple algebraic operations. I did go for the posting because the problem continues occurring even with an empty SystemSheet, where all these details should not matter.

Comment: I have the impression the problem might have been caused by calls to volatile functions in some of the worksheets.  In my case these were: OFFSET, INDIRECT and a user defined function  with some arguments declared as RANGE. I elaborated a workaround, avoiding these volatile functions and did not encounter 'eternal' looping  since.